# Using the definition of complex-differentiation to identify if a function is complex-differentiable or not

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, analysis

$g :$ \ $ \{-1\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is the function defined by: $$g(z) = \frac{\overline{z}^2}{1+z} $$

I need to use the definition of complex-differentiation to identify the $a \in \mathbb{C}$ \ {$-1$} at which $g$ is complex-differentiable or not complex-differentiable.

From the defintion I need to show that the following exists:
$$
    \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{g(a+h) - g(a)}{h}
$$

By testing the case where $a = 0$ I know that the derivative at $0$ is equal to
$$
    \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{g(h)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\bar h^2}{h(1+h)} = 0
$$

However I also need to look at the case where $a \neq 0$ which ultimately leads me to:
$$ = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} ( \frac{ \overline{a}^2 + 2\overline{ah} + \overline{h}^2}{h+h^2+ah}) - \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} (\frac{\overline{a}^2}{h+ah})$$
 However from here I am unsure of how to use the algebra of limits. I need to rearrange the above so that when I have $h$ as real, I get a different limit to when $h$ is imaginary (as I believe it is not complex differentiable).

If anyone could help me with my limits here, it would be greatly appreciated!